# Android Studio ResponseListener with AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

I've been asking a lot of questions relating to this particular code, but it seems that everytime i fix something, i run into a new error on the way, so please excuse me, i am still new to Android Studio.

I am trying to parse several double coordinates from a MySQL database using JSON parsing (query with a php script), and then placing those double values as markers in google maps.

The problem now is that even though i am parsing the double values correctly, it seems that the ResponseListener is doing too much work on the main thread (which according to an answer to one of my previous questions, shouldn't be a problem).

I am currently trying to parse 7 markers, containing marker_id, values for latitude and longitude in double and a snippet integer.

I am getting this "Error" in logcat:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I know 100% that it's the responselistener that fails to be run, as the code runs fine without.

Here is my code for the responselistener, i attempted to use an AsyncTask to run it on a backgroundthread, doing both with or without gives me the same error, which tells me that either i am using my AsyncTask wrong, or else you can't use ResponseListener in an AsyncTask:

```
public class GetMarkers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllMarkersActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading markers...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
                    while( keys.hasNext() )
                    {
                        String key = keys.next();
                        if(!key.equals("success")){   // or use this if your keys are always in digits form.. if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(key))
                            Log.v("category key", key);

                            JSONObject innerJObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
                            double latV = 1.1, lngV = 1.1;

                            String lat_str = innerJObject.getString("lat");
                            String lng_str = innerJObject.getString("lng");

                            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lat_str) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lat_str))
                            latV = Double.parseDouble(lat_str);
                            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lng_str) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lng_str))
                            lngV = Double.parseDouble(lng_str);

                            Log.i("LAT:", latV + "");
                            Log.i("LAT:", lngV + "");

                            //Random cord = new Random();

                            //double LATrangeMin = 55.6;
                            //double LATrangeMax = 55.7;

                            //double LNGrangeMin = 12.4;
                            //double LNGrangeMax = 12.7;


                            //double lat = LATrangeMin + (LATrangeMax - LATrangeMin) * cord.nextDouble();
                            //double lng = LNGrangeMin + (LNGrangeMax - LNGrangeMin) * cord.nextDouble();

                            LatLng Mplace = new LatLng(latV, lngV);

                            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(Mplace).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet:" + "0");
                            mMap.addMarker(marker);

                        }
                    }





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + response + "]");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        };

        MarkerRequest markerRequest = new MarkerRequest(responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllMarkersActivity.this);
        queue.add(markerRequest);


        return null;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

In the code i am showing i am testing for the double values that i receive. The double values are supposed to have been parsed as String from the database lat_str, and then parsed to LatV as double. However this never happens, and logcat gives me these values instead:

```
V/category key: 0
I/LAT:: 1.1
I/LNG:: 1.1
V/category key: 1
I/LAT:: 1.1
I/LNG:: 1.1
V/category key: 2
I/LAT:: 1.1
I/LNG:: 1.1
V/category key: 3
I/LAT:: 1.1
I/LNG:: 1.1
```

for all 7 keys.

This in the start succesfully places 7 markers for the Latitude 1.1 and Longitude 1.1, so in order to confirm that it retrieves 7 markers, i tried to use random lat and lng values, which places 7 markers succesfully.

So the problem lies with the parsing of latitude and longitude. I am not sure if the double values are parsed wrong, or if the main thread truly is overloaded.

When i log the innerObject i get this:

```
I/innerObject:: [{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}]
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this, or am doing something wrong with the way i am using my AsyncTask?

Also i am using Thread.sleep(); to make sure the AsyncTask even runs, if i don't then the progressdialog never even shows up.

Please answer with an example as i am still new to Android Studio :)

Thanks for the help!
Much Appreciated!

Debug Log (i think):

```
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? I/msm8974_platform:          platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2)     acdb_id(15)
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal,     acdb_id = 15, path =  0
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB ->     ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB ->     ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB ->     ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB ->     AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB ->     ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE


                                            [ 09-07 12:26:31.429 16783:17146 D/         ]
                                            Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F 
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_VOL_CAL
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE


                                            [ 09-07 12:26:31.429 16783:17146 D/         ]
                                            Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F 
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
09-07 12:26:31.429 16783-17146/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
09-07 12:26:31.435 16783-17146/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
09-07 12:26:31.428 17302-17302/? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:22441): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6346182]" dev="sockfs" ino=6346182 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.428 17302-17302/? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:22442): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6346182]" dev="sockfs" ino=6346182 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.464 23751-23751/com.apppack.myapp
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9452438
09-07 12:26:31.508 18370-18370/? W/Binder_F: type=1400 audit(0.0:22443): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6346276]" dev="sockfs" ino=6346276 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.508 18370-18370/? W/Binder_F: type=1400 audit(0.0:22444): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6346276]" dev="sockfs" ino=6346276 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.528 17302-17302/? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:22445): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6344011]" dev="sockfs" ino=6344011 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.528 17302-17302/? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:22446): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[6344011]" dev="sockfs" ino=6344011 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
09-07 12:26:31.544 16985-17019/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.apppack.myapp/.AllMarkersActivity: +97ms
09-07 12:26:31.595 23751-24512/com.apppack.myapp W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
```

Comment: are you sure you have stored in your database lat and lng as Strings and not doubles?

Comment: @Tony i tried storing lat and lng as double in database, which gives me "null" when i parse with json and log in logcat, but i just tried to store lat and lng as VARCHAR in database, and then parse, which also gives me "null", just like this:    `V/category key: 0 I/LAT:: null I/LNG:: null` maybe it's parsed wrong?

Comment: What is your log on those lines? ( Log.i("LAT:", latV + ""); ) and the other one

Comment: @Tony when i log latV/lngV i get "1.1" which tells me it never parses anything

Comment: do you know how to put breakpoints and debug your project? it would be helpful, if yes put some breakpoints on and see what happens line by line. Also, does your json has a good format? could you log the json string that you get here?

Comment: @Tony breakpoints is not exactly something i have used before. Not sure what you mean with good format with JSON, do you mean the Request itself? I could add that part to the question. Which json string do you want logged? (sorry, first time i using database with my app)

Comment: Search and see a tutorial for "Android debugging" it will help you . By good json format i mean, json has a validation form, it is created by some "rules", you can't just paste 1 line of code and say that this is your json. There are some json checkers if you google it. Log the "innerJObject"

Comment: or log the "response"

Comment: @Tony okay i think i have put the "debug" log (the part that is important) in my question, i also added the log for innerObject. When i try to log the response it just gives me "["

Comment: So you see, the response is that string you get. the lat and lng is null so you get null. Can you change these values from your database? and put some numbers to those

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ go there, copy the response you just gave it to me and paste it there, press the button validate and u will see clearly how your json looks

Comment: @Tony thats the problem. They aren't null in my database. They are stored as numbers. For an example, the first marker has these values: marker_id = 1 , lat = 55.676098 , lng = 12.34652 , snippet = 20 - before i asked the question lat and lng was stored as double, now i tried to change them to VARCHAR, which changed nothing, still parses as null

Comment: Ok, if you want to try another way simplier than async task, you could search for "Volley Libary" . It is a library making network requests and its very good.  Also check this link 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries

Comment: @Tony i am already using the volley library :)

Comment: you don't have to make the request in an async task then, cause the request it is already from it's library in an async task. If you have the url right then i don't know why you get nulls in your response string. Maybe try to make the request not in another async task

Comment: @Tony already tried that, same result :/

Comment: Debug it and see if the code inside while(key.hasNext() ) runs ..maybe it doesnt go inside that if

Comment: @Tony i thought it was pretty clear that while(key.hasNext() ) runs, there are 7 entries in my table in the database, and it logs 7 keys in logcat. Just like i posted in my question